# Assign JS variable from CSS style element

Tags: javascript, variables, modal-dialog, display

With multiple modals on a page is there a way to create a script that would close the opened modal on pressing ESC or outside the modal? The code below is an attempt to set "modal" as a variable in a JavaScript contingent on which modal has the display attribute "block."

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.modal {
 display:none;
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 right:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 z-index:1;
 }
.modal-content {
    position:relative;
    width:60%;
 min-height:40%;
 margin:8% auto;
 padding:5px;
 background:lightblue;
 }
.close{
 position:relative;
 top:0;
 left:90%;
 font-size:36px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button onclick="mod1.style.display='block'">Click A</button>
<button onclick="mod2.style.display='block'">Click me B</button> 
</div>

<div id="mod1" class="modal">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <button class="close" onclick="mod1.style.display = 'none';">&times;</button>
 <div><h3>Number 1</h3></div></div></div>

<div id="mod2" class="modal">
<div class="modal-content">
 <button class="close" onclick="mod2.style.display = 'none';">&times;</button>
 <div><h3>Number 2</h3></div></div></div>

<script>
if (document.getElementById("mod1").style.display = "block") { var modal = document.getElementById("mod1") }
if (document.getElementById("mod2").style.display = "block") { var modal = document.getElementById("mod2") }

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {modal.style.display = "none";}
}
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {modal.style.display = "none";}
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code only works for the last modal, and it has the side-effect of by default opening all modals when the page is loaded. Suggestions?

Comment: In the first two `if` conditions you've assignments instead comparisons.

Comment: @Teemu Thanks. It worked.